# Emacs gives me no error for lualatex while there ARE some errors

Tags: luatex, emacs

If I create a file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello
\directlua{tex.sprint("Yeahhh"+thisvariabledoesnotexist)}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

, revert the file, and compile with Auctex in emacs (`C-c C-c LaTeX`), I do **NOT** get any error, while it SHOULD print one since `thisvariabledoesnotexist` does not exist.

If I check the log from emacs, I can see:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `lettre_gutenberg' with ``lualatex --jobname=lettre_gutenberg  -file-line-error   --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode lettre_gutenberg.tex''
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (Web2C 2022/nixos.org) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./lettre_gutenberg.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2022-12-17>
(/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: File not found: "lmroman10-regular".))
(/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def) (./lettre_gutenberg.aux)
(/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)[\directlua]:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.7 ...ex.sprint("Yeahhh"+thisvariabledoesnotexist)}
                                                  
[1{/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./lettre_gutenberg.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:23,3:4,4:2,5:22,6:2,7:40,9:18
</nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on lettre_gutenberg.pdf (1 page, 2869 bytes).
SyncTeX written on lettre_gutenberg.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on lettre_gutenberg.log.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 1 at Fri Dec 22 22:38:19
```

so the error exists, it is just not parsed correctly apparently (and despite the `TeX exited abnormally`, emacs still tells me "Successfully formated"). Do you know how to fix this?

Note that other LaTeX errors like `ERROR: Undefined control sequence. \foo` would print as expected.

Comment: it's not a tex error and doesn't follow the syntax of tex error log so is hard for an editor to pick up. You would see similar if you used `--shell-escape` and called a command with (say) a bash commandline error.

Comment: But why can't lualatex print standard error messages? I mean, they have full freedom about how to handle such failures no? Like even in my library robust-externalize I have a nice error message (now) even when a bash/python command fails, so for a full LaTeX compiler it shouldn't be that hard to follow standards no?